# Display user profile like site.com/user1

Tags: php, url, nginx, social-networking

I want to create a simple social network with PHP, that every user has a profile that share his image and text.

I have a problem that I want to add functionality in which users will the access to his profile like Facebook , Instagram and etc like below:

`my website.com/user1`

Not this : `mywebsite.com/@user1`

Comment: use htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: Can you describe more! And if my webserver is Nginx htaccess work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use with Nginx, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415110/6749661

There are a few ways you can do this, like @MRustamzade's answer, you can change the .htaccess file to contain code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L] //update user.php?username to your users profile route.
```

You can also use a router framework, such as [Altorouter](http://altorouter.com/) which allows you to do this, and with a large number of pages.

With Altorouter you can set a number of routing rules, a simple setup could consist of:

```
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map( 'GET', '/profile/[*:username]', 'views/profile_view.php', 'home' );

$match = $router->match();

if($match) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  require $match['target'];
} else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  echo "Error 404 - File not found";
}
```

Using this code will allow you to go to `site.com/profle/username` will go to `views/profile_view.php`

In order to get the username from the URL in PHP, you can use the $match variable, something like this:

```
$username = $match["params"]["username"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `.htaccess` file and add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L] //update user.php?username to your users profile route.
```

If you have any question about `.htaccess` file then please check [this link](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much guys but my website webserver is Nginx . Can use htaccess in my website ?