# Codeigniter 4 - Azure APP service throws 404 not found - nginx/1.24.0 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure-web-app-service

I just uploaded my CodeIgniter (4.4.1) application Azure app service. The home page opens without any issues.

When we navigate to other pages, it throws an error 404 Not Found - nginx/1.24.0.

I do not see any error logged under writable/logs folder. The database is setup and working.

Comment: Issue may relate to URL rewriting or routing configuration. If that's the case, use check .htaccess for URL rewriting. Otherwise, check $baseUrl, debug remotely, test locally, check file permissions and application routes.

Comment: It works perfectly in the local server. Is there any specific .htaccess configuration for Azure nginx.

Comment: *Is there any specific .htaccess configuration for Azure nginx?* - Does this answer your question? [How can I use an .htaccess file in Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766676/how-can-i-use-an-htaccess-file-in-nginx)